# Java applet drumkit

Tags: java, applet

Hello I am trying to get a java drum kit program that I found online, because I thought it would be fun to work with, but when I compile the code the applet comes up with the buttons but no sound plays. I do not know why this is and I was wondering if I could get help fixing it. I am a beginner coder so if you know how to fix this please explain in layman's terms. Also I do have all of the sounds in the file that contains the java file and `html` file so i know its now a question of the sounds just not existing.

Here is the code...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FinalProjectst extends JApplet {

private JButton snareButton;
private JButton hiHatButton;
private JButton bassButton;
private JButton cymbalsButton;
private AudioClip snare;
private AudioClip hiHat;
private AudioClip bass;
private AudioClip cymbals;

public void init() {
    setLayout (new FlowLayout());

    sampleButtons();

    snare = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Snare.wav");
    hiHat = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "HiHat.wav");
    bass = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Kick.wav");
    cymbals = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Crash.wav");
}

private void sampleButtons() {
    snareButton = new JButton("Snare");
    hiHatButton = new JButton("Hi Hat");
    bassButton = new JButton("Kick");
    cymbalsButton = new JButton("Cymbals");

    snareButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    hiHatButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    bassButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    cymbalsButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    add(snareButton);
    add(hiHatButton);
    add(bassButton);
    add(cymbalsButton);
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == snareButton)
            snare.play();
        if (e.getSource() == hiHatButton)
            hiHat.play();
        if (e.getSource() == bassButton)
            bass.play();
        if (e.getSource() == cymbalsButton)
            cymbals.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have the audio files in your project path?

Answer (score 1):

It is failing because of `getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Snare.wav");`

As per JavaDoc `getDocumentBase()` returns the full path including file name while above `getAudioClip` expects the "`URL` representing the base location of the audio clip"

So, You can try **`getCodeBase()`** instead of getDocumentBase()

```
snare = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "Snare.wav");
hiHat = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "HiHat.wav");
```